# write to json file with array using php from data sent by ajax

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I am sending a string and an array to a php file from an AJAX request

My html looks like this

```
<form>
  <input class="description" type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

My js file looks like this

```
$('form').submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var description = $('.description').val();

    var fileNames = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg'];

    var data = {
        description,
        fileNames
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: 'details.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data)
        }
    });
});
```

My php file looks like this

```
<?php

$str = file_get_contents("test.json");

// // decode JSON
$json = json_decode($str, true);

$decodedJSON =  json_decode($str, true);
var_dump($decodedJSON);

$description = $_REQUEST;

$milliseconds = round(microtime(true) * 1000);

$description->time = $milliseconds;

file_put_contents('test.json', json_encode($description, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));

?>
```

This sets the json file as

`{"description":"test text entered","SQLiteManager_currentLangue":"2"}`

I want the json file to look like where the number is the current time in ms.

```
{
    "1495134004244": {
        "images": [
            "2.JPG"
        ],
        "description": "test"
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you getting the contents of the json file first? are you trying to append data to whats already there?

Comment: @CodeGodie yes, that is why. i actually wrote this all in node and it was working but due to hosting issues i need to use php. So ideally I would figure out now how to append to the json file but was going to try and figure that out afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redo pretty much everything. I would do it in this manner:

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="description">
    <input type="hidden" name="images[]" value="1.jpg">
    <input type="hidden" name="images[]" value="2.jpg">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'details.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data)
        }
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
// get data from request
$newArray = $_REQUEST;

// get json from file
$json = file_get_contents('test.json');

// turn json into array
$masterArr = json_decode($json, true);

// get current time in milliseconds
$milliseconds = round(microtime(true) * 1000);

// use milliseconds as array key and use the new array as its value
$masterArr["$milliseconds"] = $newArray;

// turn array back to json
$json = json_encode($masterArr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

// save json to file
file_put_contents('test.json', $json);

// echo the json so that you can use it in the AJAX call
echo $json;
```

Comment: thanks! there is one issue. the user can upload as many images as they like.

Comment: youre welcome. In that case try something like this: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: is it possible to remove `"SQLiteManager_currentLangue": "2"` from beind added to the json file?

Comment: yes its possible but I dont know where thats coming from. Are you adding anything else to the array before saving it to the json file?

Comment: @codiegodie no, not adding anything else

Comment: my assumption is that your `<form>` has extra inputs with that information.. either that or your PHP is adding extra information to the JSON, perhaps you are trying to use SQL Lite at some point.. are you dealing with any database queries in your code?